# Bootstrap Vue modal causing page jump on close / safari issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

When I close my bootstrap vue modal it causes a page jump to the section that has the open modal triggers which is fine. In Safari it is jumping well above the section where the triggers are. Is there a way to add a prevent default or similiar that will stop the page jumping when the modal is closed?

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    :visible="visible"
    size="lg"
    centered
    @hidden="closeModal"
    hide-footer
  >
    <p>
    modal body
    </p>
    <template>
      <div class="w-100">
        <b-button
          class="btn btn-icon"
          @click.prevent="closeModal"
        >
          <span class="l-btn float-left">
            <span class="btn-text">Cancel</span>
            <i class="btn-icon-symbol"></i>
          </span>
        </b-button>
        <a
          :href="$store.state.modals.interstitial.href"
          target="_blank"
          class="btn btn-icon btn-icon-arrow"
        >
          <span class="l-btn float-left">
            <span class="btn-text text-white">OK</span>
            <i class="btn-icon-symbol text-white"></i>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </template>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
import { BButton } from 'bootstrap-vue';
export default {
  name: 'Modal',
  components: {
    'b-button': BButton,
  },
  computed: {
    visible() {
      return this.$store.state.modals.interstitial.show;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    closeModal() {
      this.$store.commit('modals/setShowModal', false);
      this.$store.commit('modals/setModalHref', '');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Did you looked into the why of the jumping?

Comment: @kissu My initial thought was an href causing the jump but after some testing it did not seem to be the case. I ended up creating an event on the modal close that would scroll to the section where the modal triggers were. So when the modal closes it smooth scrolls to the section.